# Prevent vim from autofolding when typing

Tags: vim, folding, python-mode, ultisnips

Every time i use snippets in vim while coding in Python i get a problem which i desire to get rid off.
Here is the sequence of steps which leads to my problem:

1. type `fun`  and hit `Tab` to trigger snippets of a new function
   [image]
   [image]
2. start typing to define its name.
   [image]

On the last step i get all the body of my new function folded and i even don't see my cursor at the place i am currently typing.

**Info**:

- I am using `python-mode` plugin which defines foldingmethod 
  [here](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/a05d77faea3b30ebaab9b02c2cc3eff79f881fb7/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim#L40)
- I am also using `ultisnips` and `vim-snippets`.
- Here is my
  [vimrc](https://github.com/bestxolodec/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc), which contains nothing criminal as seems to me.

How could i fix such an issue?

Comment: after renaming, have your pressed `Enter`? or some key before the function was folded?

Comment: No, I have not pressed `Enter`. Every single keystroke collapses the body of a function when changing its name.

Comment: there must be some strange mappings triggered something like `zc`.  test with some plugins disabled, and try to find the plugin caused problem. you can do a "binary search"

Comment: That is great suggestion! You are extremely right. I tried to do so and figured out that YouCompleteMe plugin is the cause of such an auto folding. However i dont know know how to fix this and what next step to take for debugging such an issue. YCM brakes it even with default settings .

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with PHP code completion. It would automatically fold anything above a return statement as I typed.

I likewise narrowed the issue to the YCM plugin; I disabled all other plugins and set YCM options to defaults.

The issue went away when I set foldmethod to manual in my vimrc:

set foldmethod=manual